# SVN is it possible to commit only files that match a given extension

Tags: windows, svn

I'm using slik svn client and I wanna know if there is any way to only commit files that match a given extensions. I'm aware of the ignore prop (and hooks). But I'm wondering if there is an easy way, such as: svn commit *.cs for committing only C# files. (I've tried that and it doesn't work ;))
For me, it is easy to say commit these three file extensions and just ignore the rest.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I've added a "windows" tag, assuming that fancy Unix commands are not an option for you. Feel free to correct it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the same directory, yes, for example:

```
svn commit *.cs
svn commit path/to/subdir/*.cs
```

If they are not in the same directory, *and* you can only use DOS, then no.

If you have cygwin or Git Bash, then you could do this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.cs' -exec svn commit {} +
```

The `svn commit` command doesn't have a filtering option for selecting a subset of files, you can only use shell globs (like `*.cs`).

Comment: Thanks @janos it worked! now it's time to learn some cygwin, though ;)